# differential equation Dsolve error

Tags: differential-equations

How can ı solve the differential equation this gives error, please help

```
c = 1.0;
b = 0.1;
σ = 0.01;
n = 1.0;

w1 = -(1/3) - (2 Sqrt[g[x]])/(3*c)*Cos[y]
w2 = -((b*b)/(g[x])^(n - 1))*(1 + σ)^n/(1 - g[x] + σ)

DSolve[g'[x] == -2*g[x]*(1 - g[x] + σ)*(w1 - w2) + σ*g[x]*(1 + 3*w1), g[x], x]
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what your `y` there supposed to be (if it is a parameter, this is not a good name). If you use exact values, the errors go away. Since you are calling `DSolve` always try to avoid non-exact parameters in your ode.

```
ClearAll[x, y, g]
c = 1;
b = 1/10;
sigma = 1/100;
n = 1;
w1 = -(1/3) - (2 Sqrt[g[x]])/(3*c)*Cos[y]
w2 = -((b*b)/(g[x])^(n - 1))*(1 + sigma)^n/(1 - g[x] + sigma)
ode = g'[x] == -2*g[x]*(1 - g[x] + sigma)*(w1 - w2) + sigma*g[x]*(1 + 3*w1);
DSolve[ode, g[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The solution is implicit.

**Update:**

If initial conditions for `g(x)` is known, try `NDSolve`. For example:

```
ClearAll[x, y, g]
y = 20  Degree;
c = 1;
b = 1/10;
sigma = 1/100;
n = 1;
w1 = -(1/3) - (2 Sqrt[g[x]])/(3*c)*Cos[y]
w2 = -((b*b)/(g[x])^(n - 1))*(1 + sigma)^n/(1 - g[x] + sigma)
ode = g'[x] == -2*g[x]*(1 - g[x] + sigma)*(w1 - w2) + sigma*g[x]*(1 + 3*w1)
sol = NDSolve[{ode, g[0] == 1}, g, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To plot:

```
Plot[Evaluate[g[x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you, actually y can be any number for example 20. ı want to solve g(x) and plot g versus x, x can be any values. Please help me how can ı solve.

Comment: @merve Ok, it will work with number. Just do not use `20.0` and only use `20` to keep things exact. You can use the command `Rationalize` if needed.  DSolve works better with exact numbers. (ofcourse, this also depends on what the ODE is, in your case, exact values removed those errors you were seeing).

Comment: ı set y is 20 and the result gives Solve[...] what is the meaning, can ı have g[x]=...., and then ı want to plot g versus x.:(

Comment: @merve, first I assumed you meant `20 Degree`, since your `y` is argument to `Cos[]` and I think you mean degrees. Second, the result is implicit. Which means, the solution `g[x]` is found by solving the resulting equation, which Mathematica could not solve exactly. i.e. This is the best M can do analytically. You could always try `NDSolve` ? Your ODE is non-linear in `g(x)` and so it is hard to solve these analytically.

Comment: thank you for your help, how can ı plot the interpolatingFunction result g versus x :(

Comment: @merve added plot command. See NDSolve help page for more examples,  it is all there.